# How to use ConversationScope with vaadin?

Tags: cdi, vaadin7, conversation-scope

When using Vaadin 7.x with the CDI Addon, is it possible to use the Conversation scope (begin() and end() conversation within an UI or View? If so, where would I have to place the code to avoid side affects?

Clarification: I am on JBoss EAP6.1 (7.2) so its JEE6 with CDI1.0.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I added environment details for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The conversation scope in CDI 1.0 is tightly bound to JSF, you won't be able to use it in CDI 1.0 without doing some implementation specific hacks.

Comment: Could you give some hints how "implementation specific hacks" would have to look like? We could life with a solution that only works for EAP and Vaadin 7.1.x ...

Comment: The code is old, and I'm not sure if it still works, but you can take a look at https://github.com/seam/conversation